# How to update a file change with every iteration in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to update my file for my python program continuously, so I am using a while loop. My code is:

```
while True:
    with open("load.html", "w") as dataFile:
        dataFile.write("Information")
        dataFile.close()
```

The code below, although is functional and works, doesn't update after each edit but loads in after the while loop or program breaks/ends. How can I make it so that each edit is updated in the file with each iteration of the while loop. (I want to replace the previous data each time.)

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the file inside the while loop?

Comment: You don't have to close the dataFile, when using the context manager (with statement). On exit of the context manager, it closes the file. But that probably isn't the problem.

Comment: You are overwriting the content of `load.html` on each iteration. Either open the file *before* the loop and keep it open, or open the file in append mode.

Comment: @chepner the "Information" that is being added will be a variable that updates but for more simplicity I kept it as a string for now (The File would be blank first, second iteration new data, third iteration new data). Keeping it in append mode will make it add to the previous data, instead of replacing it. I will re-clarify that in my edit.

Comment: Are you trying to build an editor of sorts?

Comment: @DroidX86, not really, I am trying to build something that streams data. The reason for the file is that I need to transfer my data stored in a python variable to an html file so I can display it. I got the displaying part all done but I can't figure out how to update the file with each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Everytime your variable gets updated you'll need to make sure that the value of the variable is written to the file. The easiest way to do that is to overwrite the whole file and flush to disk.

Comment: @DroidX86 I tried your suggestion, but I still need to break the program to see the change.

Comment: Weird. Can you try opening the file in unbufferred mode? You have to pass 0 for the value of the `bufferring` variable.

Comment: @DroidX86 I tried your suggestion. It is weird, I thought it would work. Am I doing something wrong? `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    htmlfile = open("load.html", "w", buffering = 0)
ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O`

Comment: I guess unbufferred is only allowed in binary mode. Let's try line-Buffered. Pass Buffering as 1

Comment: @DroidX86 Now, it doesn't even load when I run my program and break it. (I waited for a good 30 seconds just in case).

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this is a `while True` loop? Why not call some `updateFile` function at the appropriate time?

Comment: @ryanwc I am trying to stream data and your idea is great but wouldn't a while loop containing an if statement checking when to call the `updateFile` function be equivalent to just the while loop. (I tried it anyways but it isn't working). Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why there is a `while` loop. Where is the data stream coming from? What code handles the data stream when it comes in? You could buffer the data as it comes in, then check if the conditions are met that you want to update the file, and if so call your `updateFile` function to overwrite the file with the buffered data.